# Add Emoji in textView then Crash Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to add emoji in textView with string value but when i am enter the text in textView application crashed and give me error:

> Fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex

```
func currentWord (_ selectedRange: NSRange, _ text: String) -> String? {
   let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\S+$")
   let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: selectedRange.location)
   if let range = regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: textRange)?.range {
       let start = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
       // Error is on the following line
       let end = text.index(start, offsetBy: range.length)
       return String(text[start..<end])
   }
   return nil
}
```

when i am enter second emoji then crash[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmuDT.png)
this line give me error[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rtR8.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show at what line is your app throwing the `fatalError` and to include the input data causing the crash.

Comment: please check i am updated my question

Comment: Please, prefer usage of [`index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3017684-index)(where it's limited by collection's `endIndex`) to `index(_:offsetBy:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code to calculate `String.Index` is wrong. It does not work when non-BMP character (for example, Emoji) is included in `text`.

Try this:

```
func currentWord(_ selectedRange: NSRange, _ text: String) -> String? {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\S+$")
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: selectedRange.location)
    if let range = regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: textRange)?.range {
        let indexRange = Range<String.Index>(range, in: text)!
        return String(text[indexRange])
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir your solution solved my problem.